# Dynamically updating the page in asp when the system is not busy

Tags: c#, asp.net

This question may be a repeated one,but please help me.I have an asp page. It contains a grid control and so many buttons. There are so many functionality like mail sending in this page. How can I dynamically update the page when the system is not busy sending messages and not doing other functions? I want to see the latest database changes in my grid.

Answer (score 1):

Use can user signalr for this. [Product Showcase / Real Time Binding](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/grid/productshowcase/signalr)

Also, here is the better example: **[Tutorial: Server Broadcast with ASP.NET SignalR (C#)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr)**

Comment: I am setting data source of grid in my page load. The fetched data table is set to grid.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with a previous post: the best way here is to use SignalR. It's a new and powerful technology.